# How to ignore text in MySQL STR_TO_DATE format string?

Tags: mysql, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to parse some dates in a MySQL table and I cannot get STR_TO_DATE to play nicely:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Tue Feb 12 17:59:59 EET 2013', '%a %b %e %T EET %Y')
```

will return null.

How can I make it ignore the **EET** text? I don't need the timezone information.

**UPDATE:** The MySQL server version is 4.1.14

Comment: Above query is working just fine.

Comment: @DoSparKot doesn't work on 4.1.14

Comment: did you tried to remove `EET` from string? `str_to_date(replace(str, ' EET ', ' '))`

Comment: @ravnur That is our current workaround. It bugs me though why it won't work with the literal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it ONLY works on 5.x (tried on 5.5.x) because of parser which can skip matched templates in string while it was not implemented in 4.x.

You can try the following statement and it would be fine in 5.x but not 4.x:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Tue XX Feb 12 17:59:59 SOME_DATA 2013', '%a XX %b %e %T SOME_DATA %Y')
```

So the best thing you can do is to follow your workaround (replace unwanted substring).

Sidenote: MySQL doesn't have concept of time zones. So MySQL doesn't care and doesn't apply any changes during date conversion if initial string contains `UTC, EET, FET` and so on.

Comment: Can you please cite the documentation on **skip matched templates in string [..] was not implemented in 4.x**? I could only find: [Literal characters in **format** must match literally in **str**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Your quote refers patterns start with `%` but not any other patterns. About citation: I can only repeat that it's my assumption why in 5.5 MySQL can understand some patterns while in 4.x it does not. Answer just one question: how MySQL can handle time zone constant (UTC...) if it doesn't support time zones.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: I want to skip EET, not parse it so I don't care the DB knows nothing about timezones - it's just a plain string! You example fails too on 4.x on both XX and SOME_DATA. I agree with you that it's probably a difference between 4.x and 5.x (btw, I know 4.x is dead), I just wanted it to be clear and coming from an official documentation rather than an assumption so I can accept your answer wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(LEFT('Wed Nov 28 20:41:25 GMT 2018',19), RIGHT('Wed Nov 28 20:41:25 GMT 2018',5)), '%a %b %d %H:%i:%s %Y');
```

This will work nicely and treats the 'GMT' as a wildcard.  In each case, the timezone is fixed to three characters.

Answer (score -1):

The names of days and months handled by %a and %b are governed by your server connection's locale setting. I am guessing from your name and timezone that you have some users whose native language isn't `'en_US'`, the default and the language of "Tue" and "Feb."

Give this command to see your locale setting:

```
  SELECT @@lc_time_names;
```

You might try issuing

```
 SET lc_time_names = 'en_US';
```

immediately before issuing the command in your question that's failing, then issuing

```
 SET lc_time_names = 'ru_RU';
```

or whatever is correct for your users immediately afterwards.

Comment: That's not the problem, we use the correct locale and `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Tue Feb 12 17:59:59 EET 2013', '%a %b %e %T')` works.